# Linq To Sql compare Time only

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How do I compare time only of DateTime Object without getting the following

Error:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

My code:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(query.DueTime);
entities = entities.Where(r => r.DueTime.TimeOfDay.Equals(date.TimeOfDay));
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the answer!

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(query.DueTime);
var time = date.TimeOfDay;
entities = entities.Where(r => DbFunctions.CreateTime(r.DueTime.Hour, r.DueTime.Minute,  r.DueTime.Second) == time);
```

Comment: I am not getting DbFunctions . It gives me error "The name DbFunctions does not exist in current context." Do i have to use any namespace int it ?

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried using the function EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(TIME) ?

it would go as follows:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(query.DueTime);
entities = entities.Where(r => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.DueTime) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(date));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This would be used for comparing dates  **ignoring time** , OP is asking for comparing time only