# How to compare minutes portion only of a TimeSpan in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, time

I have a Publication entity in my model. I want to retrieve all publications that are created less than 10 minutes from now.

```
var publications = myEntities.Publications.
    .Where(p => p.CreationUserId == exampleId
             && (DateTime.Now - p.CreationDate).Minutes < 10);
```

Trying to execute the above statement, I get the following exception: "DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.". I tried to look for an appropriate function from the DbFunctions class, but without a success. Can anybody come up with a solution to this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287730/linq-to-sql-compare-time-only

Comment: It is LINQ to Entities, my bad.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK I got Skeeted but to add to the conversation and a bit that may be useful to others...

The method you are looking for is `DbFunctions.DiffMinutes`.  It gives the total number of minutes between the two values.

```
var publications = myEntities.Publications.
    .Where(p => p.CreationUserId == exampleId
             && DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(p.CreationDate, DateTime.Now) < 10);
```

Comment: I would only use `DbFunctions` when you are comparing two `datetime` columns, instead of one column and one passed in value

Comment: Actually, I get exactly the result I wanted. I created some Publication entities the date of creation of which is 60-70 or 120-130 minutes from now and they are not part of the set. By the way, you should change the places of the two dates like so DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(p.CreationDate, DateTime.Now)

Answer (score 16):

Don't do the arithmetic in the query - do it *before* the query, so that you're basically specifying an "earliest publication creation time":

```
// Deliberate use of UtcNow - you should almost certainly be storing UTC, not
// local time...
var cutoff = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-10);
var publications = myEntities.Publications
                             .Where(p => p.CreationUserId == exampleId &&
                                         p.CreationDate >= cutoff);
```

Note that even if your original query *did* work, it wouldn't do what you wanted - it would return publications created 0-10 minutes ago, 60-70 minutes ago, 120-130 minutes ago etc. You wanted `TotalMinutes` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! However, I marked Kevin's as accepted because his answer does exactly what I wanted. By the way, as your answer is also correct, I voted it up. Hope you don't get mad at me ;) Thanks again!

Comment: @Julian: I would argue that my solution is clearer - and *may* be significantly more efficient, too... you should check the query plan. I don't mind whose answer you accept, but I think it's worth thinking about the best way of expressing the query you want...